# react TypeError: Cannot read property 'type1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm studying the react-beautiful-dnd example, and I want to add a conditional repulsion of an element, but I get an error that the field cannot be read.
This data

```
const initialData = {
tasks: {
  'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'Take out the garbage',type1: 'w' },
  'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'Watch my favorite show',type1: 'a' },
  'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Charge my phone',type1: 'h' },
  'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'Cook dinner',type1: 'w' }
},
columns: {
  'column-1': {
    id: 'column-1',
    title: 'To do',
    type2: 'all',
    taskIds: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
  },
  'column-2': {
    id: 'column-2',
    title: 'In progress',
    type2: 'w',
    taskIds: []
  },
  'column-3': {
    id: 'column-3',
    title: 'Done',
    type2: 'a',
    taskIds: []
  }
},
// Facilitate reordering of the columns
columnOrder: ['column-1', 'column-2', 'column-3']  }export default initialData
```

so they are connected

```
import initialData from './initial-data'
```

so it is assigned in state

```
state = initialData
```

this is how it is used and everything that I described it works and this is the code from the example

```
const start = this.state.columns[source.droppableId]
const finish = this.state.columns[destination.droppableId]

if (start === finish) {
  const newTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds)
```

now below i want to add my condition and it throws an error

```
    const typeDrag = this.state.tasks[source.draggableId]
const typeDrop = this.state.columns[destination.droppableId]


if(typeDrag.type1!==typeDrop.type2)
{return}
```

and I don't understand why start.taskIds works, but typeDrag.type1 reports that there is no such field

[image]

similarly executable codesandbox example
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-tutorial-forked-9c1vo?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: why .type1? Your tasks object doesn't contain this field.

Comment: Error is pointing that there is no property `[source.draggableId]` in `this.state.tasks`.
Check if `draggableId` is correct by catching in a debugger or logging into console

Comment: @VictorMolina  look carefully everything is)

Comment: @AntonTemchenko
I added a screenshot, it can be seen that the id is present

Comment: `DraggableLocation` doesn't have property `draggableId`: 
 https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/responders.md

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko ty well great job

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

instead of: `const typeDrag = this.state.tasks[source.draggableId]`
use: `const typeDrag = this.state.tasks[draggableId]`

### Explanation:

In your code `source` doesn't have property `draggableId`.
So `typeDrag` is undefined because `source.draggableId` is undefined.

Argument of your `onDragEnd` hook looks like that:

```
{
  "draggableId": "task-2",
  "type": "TASK",
  "source": {
    "index": 1,
    "droppableId": "column-1"
  },
  "destination": {
    "droppableId": "column-2",
    "index": 0
  },
  "reason": "DROP"
}
```

By checking your sandbox sample I see that you've already extracted `draggableId` property to a constant from the method argument ("result"):

```
const { destination, source, draggableId } = result; // line:28
```

So using `draggableId` instead of `source.draggableId` resolves `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type1' of undefined`.